# Naming Convention for "var" in C#

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

How do I correctly initialize a class with the `var` type? I have seen this version quite often:

```
var converter = new Converter();
```

Instances of classes should be written with PascalCase, right? Why is it different for `var`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var
"var" just a more short version

Comment: `var` is not an instance variable for the `Converter`. I suggest to read the documentation. Here `converter` is the variable and `var` is just an alias for the actual type which is `Converter`.

Comment: Reserved words in C# are lower case, and `var` is a reserved word, not a type. Having said that, there are types like `string` and `int` that are also lower case.

Comment: @DavidG Note that `string` and `int` are not directly types; they serve as keyword aliases for their respective types `String` and `Int32`. `var` doesn't have a respective type, but rather implicitly takes on the type on the right hand side of the assignment.

Comment: I think that the OP has not phrased well the question, but it is clear that he wants to know how to name (according to naming convention) the variable _converter_ He doesn't need a lesson on what var is.

Comment: @Mike So are you confused why it's `converter` and not `Converter`? Common C# convention is to use lower case for the first letter when naming variables.

Comment: @DavidG not sure if your comment is correct. This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions seems to say that you should use PascalCasing for every identifier except parameters

Comment: @Steve *[internal and private fields are not covered by guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members)* but, common practice is to use camel case in my experience.

Comment: Yes I use the same approach for local variables or for class level private variables. The important thing is how these identifiers are understandable in the context in which they are used.

Comment: @Steve I prefer to also add an underscore for class level privates, but yeah, camelCase too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `var` means and confuse between what is the class, the reference and the var (and therefore naming conventions of each).

So what `var` is? [From docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var):

> variables that are declared at method scope can have an implicit "type" var. An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type

From [Implicitly Typed Local Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var):

> The var keyword instructs the compiler to infer the type of the variable from the expression on the right side of the initialization statement

So in this case `var converter = new Converter();`:

- The compiler determines the `var` as `Converter`.
- You are creating a reference named `converter` - *which should be named using camelCaseing.*
- The explicit type of the reference is `Converter` - *which should be named using PascalCasing.*

Writing `var converter = new Converter();` is identical to writing `Converter converter = new Converter();`

---

In C# var is for for cases where you do not know the explicit type such as anonymous types or as a easy way to write:

```
Dictionary<SomeTpye, List<SomeOtherType<AndSomeGenericParameter>> variable = 
    new Dictionary<SomeTpye, List<SomeOtherType<AndSomeGenericParameter>>();
```

as this:

```
var variable = new Dictionary<SomeTpye, List<SomeOtherType<AndSomeGenericParameter>>();
```

As it is an "alias" for the type but not the type itself it keeps to the conventions of the language keywords (and not types) and is written in lower case.

Comment: But wouldn't i write otherwise:
"Converter Converter = new Converter();" ?
Why is it "var converter = new Converter();" then? Why is it small if it is of type "Converter"?

Comment: @Mike - please see update + what var actually means from the added description from documentation

Comment: @Mike Hmm... I don't understand - do you confused in the name of the object? Capital letter instead of small?

Comment: Thanks Gilad it makes sense to me. Yet, one question left: do references to classes always start with a small letter or only if "var" is used?

Comment: @Mike - by convention variables/parameters are written in camleCase - regardless to using or not using var. Classes are named using PascalCase

Comment: `var` is not just syntactic sugar. It essential when you can not express type in code, for example: when it represent anonymous type.